# How can I download all the files from a remote directory to my local directory?

Tags: linux, unix, download, wget

I want to download all the files in a specific directory of my site.

Let's say I have 3 files in my remote SFTP directory

`www.site.com/files/phone/2017-09-19-20-39-15`

- a.txt
- b.txt
- c.txt

My goal is to create a local folder on my desktop with ONLY those downloaded files. **No** parents files or parents directory needed. I am trying to get the clean report.

## I've tried

`wget -m --no-parent -l1 -nH -P ~/Desktop/phone/ www.site.com/files/phone/2017-09-19-20-39-15 --reject=index.html* -e robots=off`

## I got

[image]

## I want to get

[image]

**How do I tweak my wget command to get something like that?**

Should I use anything else other than wget ?

Comment: What does the -P parameter in your wget ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3):

Ihue,

Taking a shell programatic perspective I would recommend you try the following command line script, note I also added the citation so you can see the original threads.

```
wget -r -P ~/Desktop/phone/ -A txt www.site.com/files/phone/2017-09-19-20-39-15 --reject=index.html* -e robots=off
```

-r enables recursive retrieval. See Recursive Download for more information.

-P sets the directory prefix where all files and directories are saved to.

-A sets a whitelist for retrieving only certain file types. Strings and patterns are accepted, and both can be used in a comma separated list. See Types of Files for more information.

Ref: @don-joey
https://askubuntu.com/questions/373047/i-used-wget-to-download-html-files-where-are-the-images-in-the-file-stored

Comment: The -r seem to behave the same as -m which is the one that I have.

Comment: @ihue Yes, '-m --mirror' is a shortcut in some sense. '-r' is more explicit in my view, it does on thing. Whilst '-m' turns on options suitable for mirroring.  This option turns on recursion and time-stamping, sets infinite recursion depth and keeps FTP directory listings.  It is currently equivalent to -r -N            -l inf --no-remove-listing. (GNU Reference manual)